# Is it acceptable to use single quotes around values in HTML attributes?

Tags: css, syntax, html

Is it acceptable to use single quotes around html attribute values like this:

```
<span class='classname'>Hi</span>
```

Instead of double quotes like this:

```
<span class="classname">Hi</span>
```

Who defines what's okay? W3C?

Comment: Duplicates at least http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/html-single-quotes-a-problem and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338969/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-single-quoted-vs-double-quoted-html-a

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, that's acceptable. It works in browsers, and it's allowed by the specifications.

[The HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/spec.html#syntax-attributes) says:

> In the HTML syntax, attributes can be specified in four different ways:
>
> 1. empty attribute syntax
> 2. unquoted attribute-value syntax
> 3. **single-quoted attribute-value syntax**
> 4. double-quoted attribute-value syntax

[The HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) says:

> By default, SGML requires that all
> attribute values be delimited using
> either double quotation marks (ASCII
> decimal 34) or single quotation marks
> (ASCII decimal 39). Single quote marks
> can be included within the attribute
> value when the value is delimited by
> double quote marks, and vice versa.

Comment: Is this an acceptable answer? HTML5 is no longer officially based on SGML, and even so, you don't specify whether HTML uses this default mode.

Comment: Weird, I don't even remember writing this answer (and I usually remember).  I've updated it.

Comment: Great edit. I only commented because I found this at the top of a google search, and I figured other people might be interested.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes are and have always been completely kosher, according to the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).  It's a markup/code style choice, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the W3C publishes HTML standards.

They also provide a validator at http://validator.w3.org/

the validator is ok with both for XHTML 1.0 Strict.

There is several HTML standards, so whether it’s "acceptable" entirely depends on which you're using. Furthermore collaborative projects may have a coding style which defines to use one or the other. Using `"` is de-facto standard, even if the HTML standard may allow `'` as well.