# JQuery, How to place an image inside a div?

Tags: jquery, image, html

I am trying to place an image inside a div.

```
function pleaseW(){
    $('#info').html("Please wait ...");                         //1 this works
    $('#info').html("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />");    //2 doesn't work
    $('#info').append("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />");  //3 doesn't work
    $('#info').prepend("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />"); //4 doesn't work
}
```

The image called `busy01.gif` is in the same folder as in the current file.  The problem is that lines 2, 3, and 4 do not put an image in the div.

If I put the html directly into the page, the image shows. There has to be some unrelated problem going on with the page, as this Javascript/jQuery is perfectly valid.

Comment: so what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @RenePot, there is no image inside the div.

Comment: What happens when you try the second line?

Comment: Assuming the `src` attribute points to a valid image, lines 2, 3 and 4 should work.

Comment: Try with a different file.

Comment: Seems it does work... http://jsfiddle.net/472tN/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZZePj/1/ - every line should work

Comment: Do you have a CSS defined?

Comment: @ATOzTOA, no, I have not any css linked to this img. I also tried to remove id attribute - doesn't work

Comment: if you put `<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />` straight into your HTML ( not with JS - just hardcode it ) - does it work?

Comment: @ZoltanToth I was halfway through writing that when your comment popped up :)

Comment: @ZoltanToth, yes, without js - it works

Comment: did you use the debugger to see if any errors pop up?

Comment: There has to be some unrelated problem going on with the page, as this Javascript/jQuery is perfectly valid.

Comment: Hey, after placing the image without js (as Zoltan suggested), and removing it - it now works with js also !! It seems - solved. thanks a lot to EveryOne

Comment: @Alegro don't be happy - it might be just cached :) try in another browser or clear your cache

Comment: @ZoltanToth, Mamma Mia, whait a minute , pls

Comment: @ZoltanToth, you're right. After clearing the cache - doesn't work.

Comment: @ZoltanToth, i replaced js script from the bottom to the head of html. It works. I hope. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would work in the header but not footer.. But if it works that's good :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#info').html("<img id='busy01' style='width:100px; height:100px;' src='busy01.gif' />");
```

Comment: unless OP's got style setting to hide images, this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: But who says that the style sets dimensions to 0? Why didn't you rather set `display` and `visbility` then? Why dimensions?

Answer (score 0):

**From the Author:**

I moved the script from the bottom of the page to the head portion of the html. Now it works.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be an archaic issue with browser compatibility, not a JavaScript issue.

Each of these lines should show an image:

```
function pleaseW(){
    $('#info').html("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />");    //2 doesn't work
    $('#info').append("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />");  //3 doesn't work
    $('#info').prepend("<img id='busy01' src='busy01.gif' />"); //4 doesn't work
}
```

Comment: HTML 4 spec? What is this 1990

Comment: "By default, SGML requires that all attribute values be delimited using either double quotation marks (ASCII decimal 34) or single quotation marks (ASCII decimal 39)"

Comment: Then there is absolutely nothing wrong with that line of Javascript, and it should work.

Comment: @crush Here's a reference to the HTML5 spec: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577092/is-it-acceptable-to-use-single-quotes-around-values-in-html-attributes, as you can see they are valid. Ugly, but valid.

Comment: correct. It should work. Thus my question comment on the question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: you should link directly to the answer instead... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4577109/75642

Comment: Seems this is actually an archaic issue with browser compatibility, not a spec issue.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Sorry, I meant to link to the HTML5 spec itself. I pasted the wrong link