# Make an XmlWriter output single quotes rather than double quotes around attribute values

Tags: .net, json, escaping, quotes, xmlwriter

Is there a way to make `XmlWriter` output single quotes rather than double quotes when writing attributes?

I am *not* interested in `XmlTextWriter` which has a `QuoteChar` property (oddly not part of `XmlWriterSettings`).
Also overriding some existing writer class isn't really feasible, except perhaps for wrapping one.

Reason for asking: I'm outputting json in html data attributes, as the json quote character is " this easily leads to a little explosion in data due to " being escaped to &quot; everywhere. If I could use the single quote to start the attribute value, the double quote in the json would not require escaping.

I am outputting (x)html, and according to questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/are-single-quotes-allowed-in-html) one, single quotes are legal to delimit attribute values.

I'm pretty sure there's no (sane) way to do this, but who knows I missed something.