# jquery .html() is not replacing the innerhtml

Tags: jquery, html, insert, tags, innerhtml

I have a function that builds a string of `html`, then uses the `jquery.html()` method to insert that string of html.  I would expect the result for the page to show just the output text, but instead everything is displayed, even the tags.

```
function updateTableCell(){
   var removeDocForm = "<form action='"+docRemoveTarget+"'><a>remove</a></form><br>"
   $('table tr').eq(docRowCount).find('td').eq(4).html(removeDocForm);
}
```

I would expect just `remove` would show up when I render the page, but instead I see

`<form action='docRemoveTarget'><a>remove</a></form><br>`

Comment: What you have should work. Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net which shows the problem.

Comment: please use **double quotes** for HTML codes.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor What do you mean ? What should be changed and why ?

Comment: You are missing a `;` after your first line, could that be it?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor That's bollocks and just a matter of preference. Both ways are valid. See [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_attributes.asp) (chapter: XML Attributes Must be Quoted) and the [W3 HTML5 reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#attributes).

Comment: @dystroy : something like  `var removeDocForm = '<form action="'+docRemoveTarget+'"><a>remove</a></form>"`

Comment: If you want to insert content at 4th cell of a row, you can use this `$('table tr td:nth-child(4)').html(removeDocForm);`

Comment: @Oldskool yes, both single & double quotes are valid. But for most scripts in the Internet, they use double quotes. Let's use double quotes in HTML wherever possible!

Comment: try code its already working...i have tested it and only remove is appear in but as aspected html is replaced..what else you want

Comment: @Oldskool extended readings: http://stackoverflow.com/q/273354/188331

Comment: Your code worked for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zKw5V/

Comment: @Oldskool w3schools is known to be inaccurate. [w3fools](http://w3fools.com). the technical report for html 5 has an unquoted attribute syntax defined http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - On what do you base your statement "most scripts in the internet, they use double-quotes"? Has somebody double-checked every page on the net and confirmed that more that half use double quotes? The answers for the question you linked to support Oldskool's view that single quotes are fine. Which they are.

Comment: @nnnnnn i just posted the SO question for extended information in other views. Do you find a lot of scripts / HTML codes using single quotes? I doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your code and tested its worked. Code is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateTableCell()
{
    var docRemoveTarget = "localhost.php"
    var removeDocForm = "<form action='"+docRemoveTarget+"'><a>remove</a></form><br>";
    $('table tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(4).html(removeDocForm);
    console.log($('table tr').eq(0));
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    updateTableCell();
});
</script>
<table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr height="30">
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
        <td style="border:1px solid #CCC;"> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: may be you are selecting dom that actually not there because in eq index start from 0 and you might accessing or getting dom that are not there..