# How to add anchor to <td> tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.each(obj.query, function(k,v) {
  var tbl_row = "";

  $.each(this, function(k , v) {
    tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
  })
  tbl_row += "<td><a href='#' onclick='"+javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);+"'>Delete</a></td>";
  tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                
})
$("#201").html(tbl_body);
```

I need to add a link to a tab and call a javascript function and if I just add the `<a>` tag it will work but when I add `href=""` and `onclick=""` it will not work. This is an AJAX call data printed in dynamic table.

Comment: Look at the code highlighting in the question. Do you see what might be the problem?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: Put single quotes around # - not double quotes.  They're the delimiter for the string you're constructing.

Comment: @user2422387 do you notice anything odd about the color of the text in your question? like turning from red to gray?

Comment: but still not working

Comment: @koala_dev thats not me it is edited and higlight by holodoc

Comment: no, that is you, that's how your original question looked, see @chris' answer below

Comment: @user2422387 I only made a few corrections to your text and removed the redundant `CodeIgniter` tag. The code is exactly the way you wrote it.

Comment: @holodoc you should have removed `php` tag too ;)

Comment: @itachi Missed it somehow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is using jquery's "on" event listener which allows bind event listener to dynamic added html elements. Here is what I suggest:

**First change:**

```
tbl_row += "<td><a href="#" onclick='"+javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);+"'>Delete</a></td>";
```

**to:**

```
tbl_row += '<td><a href="#" id="makeajaxCallTirggerId" data-ajaxParam=' + v.uID + '>Delete</a></td>';
```

**Then in your java script do the following;**

```
$(document).on('click', '#makeajaxCallTirggerId', function(e){
   makeajaxcall($(this).attr('data-ajaxParam'));
});
```

Comment: How did you manage to repeat the very same mistake that OP made and give an answer to, well something, in the process?

Comment: @zhumingvictor copy/paste syntax error still exists in your "to" section

Comment: This is ok i am set the values in anchor tag but cannot do now because makeajaxcall is called outside

Comment: The parameter to the function can be save in the anchor dom, and then retrieved from dom. See the changes I did.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of doing the work for you...

change

```
tbl_row += "<td><a href="#" onclick='"+javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);+"'>Delete</a></td>";
```

to

```
tbl_row += "<td><a href='#' onclick='"+javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);+"'>Delete</a></td>";
```

...notice the difference in the syntax highlighting, that gives the answer away...

The problem is that you're trying to add href="" and onclick="" to a string surrounded by " ". You need to be adding href='' and onclick='' instead. see this post for a similar situation [Are single quotes allowed in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/are-single-quotes-allowed-in-html)

**EDIT**
If I understand correctly, the actual problem the OP is facing is that if the call to *javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);* fails, the creation of the table also fails. **So what *it appears that* the OP actually needs is a way to gracefully continue with the creation of the table, even if an error occurs.**

The best way to deal with that is to wrap the contents of the function in a **try/catch**. If you do that inside the makeajaxcall function, it'd be best.

**The code we really need to see is the code in your makeajaxcall function, as that seems to be where the problem lies.**

Comment: It's likely that the OP meant to write `onclick="makeajaxcall(v.uID);"` instead of concatenating the function's return value.

Comment: @user2422387 "not working" has no meaning, on Stack Overflow. Are you getting an error message, or is there an error showing in the web/js console of your favorite browser?

Comment: @Juhana this could be. user2422387 could you clarify if that's the case?

Comment: hey there is no error it is not working if there is a small problem in ajax call even no error messages do you know @chris.nesbit1

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't do what you want because of your quotes. You're not ending them when you want and the onclick function should be in HTML quotes. It should look something like this.

```
tbl_row += "<td><a href='#' onclick='javascript:makeajaxcall(v.uID);'>Delete</a></td>";
```

That's why in JavaScript and PHP I always use single quote(') and in HTML I always use double quote(").

Comment: Well that's because your onclick doesn't work. You want it to make an ajax call on the click. The link doesn't know anything about v when it's clicked. I suggest putting in some IDs but if you know this format isn't going to change you could do this
`onclick='makeajaxcall(this).parent().first());'`