# Where to add the ID in a URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, seo, url-design

I’m using friendly URLs, like so:

```
http://localhost/gallery/photo/this-is-a-url-friendly-photo-caption
```

On the friendly URL, I need to add the ID of the photo, but looking around, I’ve seen two ways of adding the ID to the friendly URL, pre and post, like so

```
http://localhost/gallery/photo/this-is-a-url-friendly-photo-caption.529
```

or

```
http://localhost/gallery/photo/529/this-is-a-url-friendly-photo-caption
```

Is there an advantage using one way? Or it’s just a question of preference / personal taste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small advantage of having the ID in the second last and the slug in the last path segment (`/gallery/photo/529/this-is…`):

In some contexts the URL might get cut off, [for example by a line break in plain text emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143295/193139). If the ID comes *before* the (usually long) slug, there’s a higher chance that the ID stays intact and the URL can keep functioning (assuming that you redirect to the canonical variant with slug).

#### Example

Your question currently has this URL:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343034/seo-friendly-url-where-to-add-the-id

When it gets cut off like that (= the ID stays intact), it redirects to the canonical variant and the user is happy:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343034/seo 
>   -friendly-url-where-to-add-the-id

But when it gets cut off like that (= a different ID), the user is not so happy (because the link leads to a different page):

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273430 
>   34/seo-friendly-url-where-to-add-the-id