# how to get rounded cells for my table

Tags: html, css, tcpdf

I am trying to get rounded cells for my table but I am unable to execute css as border-radius is not working in my code i.e.,
    
    table 
        {
        border-spacing: 10px;
        border-collapse: seperate;
        }

```
 <tr>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#FE0000; color:white;  text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#F69546; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#92D14F; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxx</b></td>
```

here I am using tcpdf and html

Comment: `style=\"...."` shouldn't have backslash and you have a closing tag `</b>` with not opening one.

Comment: but i need to keep backlash because I am writing this html for generating pdf......!!!

Comment: how is this `PHP` related?

Comment: I am using TCPDF and inside $html ="html code here";

Comment: then you should change  `$html ="html code here"` to  `$html ='html code here'` then remove the `blackslash`'s

Comment: I am able to run pdf, but only border-radius is not working !!!! other html codes are working

Answer (score 1):

Give `border-radius` for child element of the td .

```css
td b{
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:block;
  padding: 10px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
<tr>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#FE0000; color:white;  text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#F69546; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
<td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#92D14F; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxx</b></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: this code is working in palin html but in TCPDF conversion is not working specially border radius it shows only rectangle box.

Comment: This html code was copied from you question, then why? Give a width and height for the element and give border-radius, then it will be rounded element. answer is  updated please check.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `php` singular quotes `' '` with `html` with double quotes on `attributes` `" "`

**See : [LINK (SO Question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/are-single-quotes-allowed-in-html)**

**UPDATED: added `table` opening and closing tags and `tr` closing tag**

change `$html` to

```
$html ="
<table>
      <tr>
         <td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#FE0000; color:white;  text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#F69546; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style=\"border:1px solid black; background-color:#92D14F; color:white; text-align:center;\"><b>xxxxxxxxx</b></td>
     </tr>
</table>
";
```

to

```
$html ='
<table>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#FE0000; color:white;  text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#F69546; color:white; text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#92D14F; color:white; text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxx</b></td>
     </tr>
</table>
';
```

also try using this to echo the css if not already included.

```
$html = "table { border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: seperate; }";
```

or

```
$html = "td b { border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: seperate; }";
```

Comment: I also tried this one html running succesfully but I am unable to get border-radius function working !!!

Comment: ya css is already includeed in my code <style>
table 
  {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  border-collapse: seperate;
  
  }
</style>

Comment: @sivasanker then you should try the updated table html.

Comment: sorry but I didn't understand your comment completely

Comment: try this : 
$html ='
<table>
      <tr>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#FE0000; color:white;  text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#F69546; color:white; text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxxxx</b></td>
         <td style="border:1px solid black; background-color:#92D14F; color:white; text-align:center;"><b>xxxxxxxxx</b></td>
     </tr>
</table>
';

 and this : 
$html = "td b { border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: seperate; }";

Comment: @sivasanker Join this chat so we can the question resolved: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102693/how-to-get-rounded-cells-for-my-table

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF has a very limited CSS support. It doesn't support all attributes.

Currently, only the following CSS attributes are supported:

font-family
font-size
font-weight
font-style
color
background-color
text-decoration
width
height
text-align