# Are Single Quotes Valid in a Doctype?

Tags: html, xhtml, quotes, doctype

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/when-did-single-quotes-in-html-become-so-popular), single quotes in html has either become more popular or we have begun to notice them more often.

Regardless, I have a related question.  The `HTML 4.01 Strict` doctype as shown at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) (below) uses double quotes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

As stated in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/when-did-single-quotes-in-html-become-so-popular/242775#242775), single quotes are perfectly valid. However, the quoted values in the doctype aren't necessarily attributes so are single quotes permitted?  In other words, is the following a valid doctype?  Furthermore, if this is valid HTML, is it accepted by modern browsers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd'>
```

Also, does the same hold true for XML doctypes?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

Comment: In what case would you need to use single quotes instead of double quotes for your doctype?

Comment: Well, you would never "need" to.  That doesn't make it invalid though, and certainly doesn't satisfy my curiosity about the spec.  =)

Comment: The same does hold true for the XML Declaration. Which isn't a doctype, does something quite different, and should generally be omitted if it's just `version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'` (which it usually is). http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-XMLDecl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, both are valid.

See the [SGML spec](http://xml.coverpages.org//sgmlsyn/sgmlsyn.htm#P110). At some point while drilling through all links for the doctype declaration, you'll end up at the "[system identifier](http://xml.coverpages.org//sgmlsyn/sgmlsyn.htm#P75)" specification (the parts containing quotes), which is defined as:

```
( lit , "
system data [45] ,
lit ) | "
( lita ,    '
system data [45] ,
lita )  '
```

The definition syntax is weird, but it appears that either single or double quotes are allowed (it's similar to the attribute values definition).

A doctype with single quotes also seems to [validate](http://validator.w3.org/check) just fine.

Comment: fyi, Python xml.dom.minidom produces doctypes with single quotes, while Apple XCode only performs syntax highlighting on ones with double quotes. So this is useful information!