# html tag not showing image when passing value at runtime using c#

Tags: c#, html

i am using html page to send a mail, in which i am parsing the tags to give their value at run time.. but my problem is i have two img src tags. i am giving them value at run time, but as the mail is recieved it is showing only one image not both..
i don't know what might be the problem is. i am using the below code:

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                 XmlNode node = null;
                 xmlDoc.Load(theme);
                 XmlNodeList list = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("html/body/form/div/img");
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                string from = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["from"];
                string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
                string smtp_port = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtp_port"];

                if(foot_image!= "")
                {
                    Attachment imgAtt = new Attachment(foot_image);
                    imgAtt.ContentId = footimage;
                    imgAtt.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                    list.Item(1).Attributes[0].Value = "cid:" + imgAtt.ContentId + "";
                    mail.Attachments.Add(imgAtt);
                }

                if(file != "")
                {
                    Attachment ingatt1 = new Attachment(file);
                    ingatt1.ContentId = headimage;
                    ingatt1.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                    list.Item(0).Attributes[0].Value = "cid:" + ingatt1.ContentId + "";
                  //  node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("html/body/form/div/img");
                  //  node.Attributes[0].Value = "cid:" + ingatt1.ContentId + "";
                    mail.Attachments.Add(ingatt1);
                }

                xmlDoc.Save(theme);

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(theme);
                string theme_text = sr.ReadToEnd();

                mail.To.Add(to);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(from);
                mail.Subject = "In line image test";
                mail.Body = theme_text;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

please sort out my problem..

my html page is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div style="margin-left:50px; padding-top:10px">
        <img src="" style="width:480px; height:150px;" />
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:50px; padding-top:20px;">
        <h1>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div style="margin-left:50px; margin-top:200px;">
        <img src='' style="width:480px; height:150px;" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should tag this properly. That looks like C#, not just HTML.

Comment: i think i should move to any other site for my problems..

Comment: That's up to you, but it's really not that difficult to get it right.

Comment: @jayp: that's what i am not getting to how to get right..please provide me the solution..

Comment: can please anyone provide me the possible answer????

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? This seems like it would be very simple to fix if you were able to test a few of your variables.

Comment: @albertvo:yes i tested. but it seems allright to me..

Comment: using debugger, the theme_text showing both the src's value, but recieved mail shows only second image but not both..

Comment: so you are saying that when you set a breakpoint on the line "xmlDoc.Save(theme);" and inspect "xmlDoc", it's xml values are correct?

Comment: @albertvo: yes it is saving the values which are passed to it..

Comment: When you received the email, are both images attached to the email as well?

Comment: @albertvo: yes i recieved both the images but one image come as attachment..but according my code both have to come in body....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information I have from our comment thread, there is a problem with the second image being attached to the email correctly. Try sending to a different email address to see if the problem still exists. There could be some spam filtering going on thats blocking that specific image.

Answer (score 0):

In 2nd img tag you have used src='' instead of src="", so problem exists.

Comment: There should be no difference - both single and double quotes are allowed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs Also, the question is closed back in 2011, so the problem is likely fixed.