# How to use addClass / removeClass on dynamically created DOM elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function that is called in document.ready() that creates spans.

```
function configureContentSelector() {
  for (j=0; j<centerContent.length; j++)
    {
        var content = "<span class='contentSelector' onclick='changeContent(" + j + ")' id='span'" + j + ">" + j  + "</span>";
        $("#contentSelectorArea").html($("#contentSelectorArea").html() + content); 

   }
```

Note the spans are id-ed as span0, span1 etc.

Within a separate function that is called when an event unrelated to the spans is fired I want to manipulate the span classes (addClass() removeClass())

```
$("#" + "span" + i).removeClass("contentSelector");
$("#" + "span" + i).addClass("contentSelectorSelected");
```

However, this does not work. I believe this issue is related to the fact that the spans are created dynamically but I do not know how to fix this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: once spans are inserted into the DOM you can call `addClass` or `removeClass` on them

Comment: What's the function in which you are manipulating the classes?  and what is the value of `i` in your add/removeClass?

Answer (score 3):

You create wrong `id`s (all of them have id=span):

```
var content = "<span class='contentSelector' onclick='changeContent(" + j + ")' id='span'" + j + ">" + j  + "</span>";
```

Try this:

```
var content = "<span class='contentSelector' onclick='changeContent(" + j + ")' id='span" + j + "'>" + j  + "</span>";
```

BTW your quotes should be *reversed*:

```
var content = '<span class="contentSelector" onclick="changeContent(' + j + ')" id="span' + j + '">' + j  + '</span>';
```

Comment: BTW: I thought the order of quotes did not matter (single inside of double or visa versa).

Comment: Well it seems it doesn't really matters ([check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs)), most times (in my experience) people use `"` in html attributes, so (at least for me) it feels more *natural*.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is an error here

```
id='span'" + j + ">"
```

change to

```
id='span" + j + "'>"
```

and use

```
$("#contentSelectorArea").append(content);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the ID and use a `data-*` attribute (Theres a syntax error with your ID declaration anyway).

```
var content = "<span class='contentSelector' onclick='changeContent(" + j + ")' data-spanid='" + j + "'>" + j  + "</span>";
```

Then you can select using the `data-*` attribute:

```
$("span[data-spanid='" + i + "']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a simple error during the creation of your control. Check the quotes in the id attribute that gets created.

Use this and it'll work fine.

```
var content = "<span class='contentSelector' onclick='changeContent(" + j + ")' id='span" + j + "'>" + j  + "</span>";
```