# HTML Coding - Is there a benefit disadvantage to using "quotes" or "apostrophes"?

Tags: css, html, web-standards

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Single vs Double quotes (' vs ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs)

I just purchased an HTML template built on Twitter Bootstrap. Parts of the template are coded with `class='navbar'` rather than `class="navbar"` (notice the apostrophes rather than quotation marks for the class attribute).

**Is there a benefit or disadvantage to using apostrophes over quotation marks?**

Comment: The single apostrophes obviously take up less space. (I had a teacher in elementary school that insisted we save our Oregon Trail characters in all lowercase, as it would take up less space on the disk)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. You're entirely free to use either.

One of the reasons both exist is so it's less work to work with them in javascript.

```
var lumpOfHTML="<a href='http://google.com'>Link 1</a>";
var anotherLumpOfHTML='<a href="http://google.com">Link 1</a>';
```

Both of these will do the same thing.

Comment: I guess my issue is that some of the template uses quotes as in `href="../index.html"` but the classes and id attributes use apostrophes as in `class='navbar'`. Seems frustrating so far. Any idea how to streamline this? (I use Dreamweaver CS6, and the site will end up being PHP)

Answer (score 1):

It's a personal preference.

BTW: In HTML5 is it allowed to not use quotes eg.  `class=navbar` if te value is 1 word

Comment: do you have a source for that? I'm not sure I've seen that before.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attributes says:

an unquoted attribute value is specified by providing the following parts in exactly the following order:
an attribute name; 
zero or more space characters;  
a single "=" character; 
zero or more space characters; 
an attribute value

 ( @Tuanderful )

Comment: Not just HTML5. All versions of HTML except the XHTML variants have allowed that.

Comment: Really @Alohci ? I know it would work in the browser, but this would make for "invalid HTML" (That what I thought at least)

Comment: ah, i misread your answer as "in HTML5, it is not allowed to use quotes if the value is one word"

Comment: @gar_onn - It's perfectly valid. For example, see the [HTML 2.0 spec](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 14, sectiop 3.2.4. Attributes, second bullet point.