# Pass value from loop to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have following code:

```
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.name); 
var mytable = "<table> cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr>"; 
for (var i = 0; i < storedNames.length; i++) {   
  if (i % 2 == 1 && i != 1) {
     mytable += "</tr><tr>";   
  }

    mytable += "<td>" + storedNames[i].name +" "+ storedNames[i].email+"</td><td><img id='arrow' src='arrow.png' height='20' width='20' onclick='redirectToDetail();' ></td></tr>"; 
} 

mytable += "</tbody></table>";

document.write(mytable);
```

here, in redirectToDetail function i want to i value . How can I pass this?
Any idea?
thank u in advance

Comment: Where is your redirectToDetail function?

Comment: No redirectToDetail function here..

Comment: `var mytable = "<table> cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr>";` or `var mytable = "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr>";`?

Comment: @Narek Answers should be posted as Answers. It isn't really the appropriate place in the comments section.

Comment: @FeistyMango this is **not answer**, just wrong syntax notice.

Comment: @Narek Duely noted. However, his syntax is completely valid. Html standard allow him to use either single quotes or double quotes for attributes. In this case, he chose to use single quotes within his html template strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs

Comment: @FeistyMango do we speak about same thing? :) Check symbol after `<table`

Comment: @Narek Ahh, I see what you mean. I thought you were making an issue of the quotes. Doh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the value as a literal constant that is passed to the onclick event and you are home free. In addition, I would strongly encourage you to consider using an array and joining the strings as you will yield much better performance particularly in IE.

```
var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.name); 
var mytable = ['<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr>'];
for (var i = 0; i < storedNames.length; i++) {   
  if (i % 2 == 1 && i != 1) {
     mytable.push("</tr><tr>");   
  }
  mytable.push('<td>' + storedNames[i].name + ' ' + storedNames[i].email + '</td><td><img id="arrow" src="arrow.png" height="20" width="20" onclick="redirectToDetail(' + i + '"></td></tr>"');
} 

mytable.push("</tbody></table>");

document.write(mytable.join());
```

Now you can declare you onclick function like so:

```
function redirectToDetail(value) {
   //do stuff with the value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 mytable += "<td>" + storedNames[i].name +" "+ storedNames[i].email+"</td><td><img id='arrow' src='arrow.png' height='20' width='20' onclick='redirectToDetail(\'"+ i +"\');' ></td></tr>";
```

and take that in `redirectToDetail`

```
 function redirectToDetail(val){
     alert(val);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
onclick='redirectToDetail(\'"+i+"\')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do. check it.

```
mytable += "<td>" + storedNames[i].name +" "+ storedNames[i].email+"</td><td><img id='arrow' src='arrow.png' height='20' width='20' onclick='redirectToDetail(" + i + ");' ></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Ok. I think you noticed this unwanted > in var mytable = "<table> cellpadding=\"0\"

Comment: Also in your code pairing issue for tag <tr>. For eg if storedNames.length == 0