# HTML Checkbox selected Element keep tick after submit

Tags: php

I have check box set when i submit it, i want keep tick what i selected, I have wrote a code but I want to know any easiest way to do it

```
<form action="" method="post">


                    <input type="checkbox" name="car[]"  
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
                                if(isset($_POST['car'])){
                                if(in_array('Bus',$_POST['car']))
                                    { 
                                        echo  ' checked="checked"" '; 
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        ?> value="Bus" />Bus
        <input type="checkbox" name="car[]" value="Van" 
                        <?php 
                            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
                            { 
                                if(isset($_POST['car'])){
                                    if(in_array('Van',$_POST['car']))
                                    { 
                                        echo  ' checked="checked"" '; 
                                    }
                                }
                            } ?> />Van

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: give your html for better look of problem

Comment: Use `echo  ' checked="checked" ';`  instead of `echo  ' checked="checked"" ';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the vehicles, and print out the items accordingly (with their corresponding checked values), in one fell swoop. Something like this would work:

```
$vehicles = array('Bus', 'Van'); // You can add as many as you want!

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    // Should it be checked?
    $checked = '';
    if(isset($_POST['car'])) {
        if(in_array($vehicle,$_POST['car']) $checked="checked='checked'";
    }

    // Add the element
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='car[]' value='{$vehicle}' {$checked}> 
        {$vehicle}";
}
```

Comment: HTML uses double quotes (`"`), not single quotes.

Comment: @arkascha I referred to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs