# meta tags apostroph and Quotation mark

Tags: html, meta-tags, w3c-validation

Some seo guy told me that I should not use apostroph in meta-tags, because it is not w3c conform.
I tried with several doctypes, transitional, strict , html5... and got no errors shown.

```
<link rel='canonical' href='someurl' />
```

So what is right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Single vs Double quotes (' vs ")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the HTML5 CR, [8.1.2.3 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/syntax.html#attributes-0).

There are four ways how attributes can be specified:

- Empty attribute syntax
- Unquoted attribute value syntax
- Single-quoted attribute value syntax (using `'` (U+0027))
- Double-quoted attribute value syntax (using `"` (U+0022))

So yes, you may use `'`. In that case, the attribute value may not contain other `'` characters (you’d have to encode them).