# Avoid escape characters in PHP echo

Tags: php

Is there a way to avoid the \ escape character in an echo?  This works fine but is hard to read.  What is the recommended way to handle this?

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<td><input id=\"EmpFirstName\" name=\"EmpFirstName\" type=\"text\" value=\"" . $row['EmpFirstName'] . "\"></td>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single-quotes for the HTML attributes:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<td><input id='EmpFirstName' name='EmpFirstName' type='text' value='{$row['EmpFirstName']}'></td>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

It doesn't matter if you use single-quotes or double-quotes for HTML attributes. (See the Stack Overflow question [Single vs Double quotes (' vs ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs) )

I also changed `".$row['EmpFirstName']."` to `{$row['EmpFirstName']}`, which is slightly cleaner, and equally valid in PHP when using `echo "";`.

Comment: `'$row[EmpFirstName]'` is even more cleaner

Comment: it is not the same as I posted it and it will produce an error