# GWT Element attribute removes quotes in IE

Tags: java, javascript, gwt

`com.google.gwt.user.client.Element` removes quotes in attributes when Application works on IE. I have element with `<div id="mytestid"> </div>`. I want to remove this id and set a new one, but when app runs on IE (I use IE9) I can not change the id properly because it puts single or double quotes around my id.

For example:

```
      Element el = elem;
      el.removeAttribute("id");
      String id = "\"mynewid"\";  //I tried all possible combinations foe escaping  
      el.setAttribute("id", id);
```

But Element id is `id='"mynewid"'`  - it puts single quotes around double quotes.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, you have quotes in your value, and you complain that IE is using them as-is? (the single quotes are so that your double quotes are not interpreted as quotes around the value, but part of the value; IE could have serialized it as `id="&quot;mynewid&quot;"` too)

Comment: The problem is that if  I set id to element on internet explorer this id of element is not in quotes
THanks

Comment: Single and double quotes are allowed for attributes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs If you set the Attribues value to "value" the Browser needs to either escape  the quotes &amp;quot; or escape with the other attribute "terminator"

Comment: single quotes and double quotes are used interchangeably in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is wrong with this?

Its working as expected. You have set it `"mynewid"` by using `id = "\"mynewid\""`.

Try this one if you don't want double quotes around new id.

```
  Element el = elem;
  el.removeAttribute("id");
  String id = "mynewid";  
  el.setAttribute("id", id);
```

Screenshot - Firefox 26.0

[image]

Screenshot - IE9

[image]

Comment: I want double quotes around my new id but I do not see them on IE :)

Comment: I have attached the screenshot for IE9. Is this what you want?

Comment: Also, don't trust the serialization in IE Dev Tools; get the ID value and `alert()` it or `console.log()` it or whatever.