# Sublime Text: ignore double quotes and display correct colors for HTML tags

Tags: sublimetext3

I used to write HTML attribute values without double quotes. That makes the HTML code look very clean. Take [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs/30114712#30114712) as an example.

However, such a style causes Sublime to display tag colors incorrectly. In the following picture, since `<div id=wrapper>` has no double quotes around `wrapper`, Sublime does not show any color after that line (but how come everything looks OK before that line?).

Is there any way that I can set Sublime to ignore the double quotes and display correct colors?

[image]

Comment: I used to use Bluefish. It does not care about double quotes and always display tag colors correctly. ;-)

Comment: This is invalid HTML, as explained in the question you linked.

Comment: Well, the www.w3.org does talk about `Unquoted attribute-value syntax`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-unquoted

Comment: Invalid SGML, valid HTML. Either way, you should just use quotes (or find a way to write your own syntax parser in sublime text).

Comment: But we are in the HTML world, not SGML, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is redefine the syntax definitions in Sublime Text. You can also do this on the user level. Two great resources for doing this are [here](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) and [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html). They're very well written.

With that said, I’m using build 3083 right now and I can’t replicate your issue. A quick update might be all you need. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Text has a setting called "HTML/XML Attributes" that can be customized to handle this scenario. You can add the following setting to your Sublime Text user settings file to ignore the double quotes:
Json

```json
"auto_complete_html_attributes": false
```

This setting will turn off auto-completion for HTML/XML attributes in Sublime Text and allow the display of tag colors correctly. To access the user settings file, go to Preferences > Settings.