# How to replace single quotes with double quotes in Angular expression syntax + html

Tags: html, angularjs

In the below code snippet i want to replace string in single quote to string in double quote. is there any way to do that

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{ 'text-success': $first }" ng-repeat="item in items"
    {{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

when i tried doing it by adding escape character, angular logged an error
"Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 1-1 [] in expression [{\]

Comment: where is the code

Comment: Why you need to do that? If you replace, I think it won't work

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class='{ "text-success": $first }' ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

I don't know why you would want it like this though.

Comment: I want to use double quote only

Comment: @Bandesh29 sometimes it better we amend to standards, because your today's code, may be the problem of someone's tomorrow code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs

Comment: You can change your class name to not contain dash. For example: `textSuccess`. Then quotes around it won't be needed.