# Extracting json out of data attribute with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get data out of a data attribute using jquery.

Heres what I have:

```
<div id="x" data-foo="{top:'100', left:'40', width:'50'}">
```

and in javascript:

```
x = $('#x').data();

console.log( x.foo.top ) //undefined
```

Ive tried JSON parse as well, but I get errors about unexpected tokens then.

Comment: `data.foo` is a string.  It doesn't automatically know that the string value contains JSON content.

Comment: @amy yeah that seems to be the root of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please arrange your code like this

```
 <div id="x" data-foo='{"top":"100", "left":"40", "width":"50"}'> 

 In JSON, Key will be double quote.
```

Comment: @JasonLough Please go to the link and test it. https://jsfiddle.net/ahscse/gvu48Lqc/

Comment: @JasonLough If this is the answer, click the checkmark to accept it.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: As this question has been downvoted most likely because of suggesting to use single instead of double quotes: [both are legit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs). I would recommend to stick to either single or double quote and use `&quot;` inside your `data-foo` value, otherwise this may be a cause of problems if someone else has to maintain your code.

Comment: @JasonLough you can click Check mark (it will be selected)  but not up or down Key

Answer (score 2):

You can get data with jQuery attr
`x = $('#x').attr('data-foo');`
And then parse it to json like:
`var data = JSON.parse(x)`

Comment: `.data('foo')` gets the attribute value.  No need for `attr`.

Comment: Same issue. The challenge is to set the data in the attribute with the HTML. It did get me thinking about how the string was formatted though. I think I have the answer, one sec to confirm.

Comment: Yep, if you format the string properly, you can use it as a JSON object, otherwise you get errors trying to parse or access the keys. Proper string in my eample would be (note the use of quotes): '{"top":"100", "left":"40", "width":"50"}'

Answer (score 0):

What you have in `data-foo` is the string for a `Javascript Object Literal` and not `JSON`

Firstly, you need your JSON formatted properly. See below.

```
<div id="x" data-foo='{"top":"100", "left":"40", "width":"50"}'></div>
```

Read more about that here.

https://medium.com/@easyexpresssoft/object-literal-vs-json-7a2084872907

Then, use `JSON.parse()` to get your data

```
var x = JSON.parse($('#x').attr("data-foo"));
alert( x.top );
```

Hope it helps