# TypeScript function to set height in NgStyle does not work

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have designed a shape and I want to determine its height based on a TypeScript-function, but the `ngStyle` does not apply the height to the shape.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = "card" [ngStyle] = "{'height': CalculateHeight()}" (click) = 'onSelect()'>
```

**Function:**

```
CalculateHeight(): number {
  let CardHeight = ((this.Card.duration.Hours * 60) +
    (this.Card.duration.Minutes)) * 2;

  if (CardHeight <= 60) {
    CardHeight = 60;
  }

  console.log(CardHeight);

  return CardHeight;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Hi @Dorian, as you can see there ar several answers to your question. Please mark as the right answer, if someone solved your issue. To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CalculateHeight` returns just a number. But `height` to work properly, there need to be the `unit` as well.

Try the following line.

```
< div class = "card" [ngStyle] = "{'height.px': CalculateHeight()}" (click) = 'onSelect()' >
```

Note the **.px**. It will do the trick.

OR. you can make `CalculateHeight` to return a string with the height unit attached at the end. For example **400px**.

Comment: Would be nice if can include the way of `[style.height.px]="CalculateHeight()"` too

Answer (score 3):

You will also need px in your html file like this

```
<div class="card" [ngStyle]="{'height': CalculateHeight() + 'px'}" (click)="onSelect()">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't set any unit to your height.. its like "300 what?, eggs?, cars?, pixels?" :P

Just return your result with a valid unit. This could simply be done by adding `+ 'px'` to your returned value:

```
CalculateHeight(): number {
  let CardHeight = ((this.Card.duration.Hours * 60) +
    (this.Card.duration.Minutes)) * 2;

  if (CardHeight <= 60) {
    CardHeight = 60;
  }

  console.log(CardHeight);

  return CardHeight + 'px';
}
```

> You should also change your HTML from `(click)='onSelect()'` to `(click)="onSelect()"` because its recommend to use doublequotes instead of singlequotes, when quoting attributes values.
>
> To learn more take a look at the recommend [style-rules](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Style_Rules), especialy for [HTML Quotation Marks](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#HTML_Quotation_Marks).

Comment: @Icycool yes, i've never seen this before and tried it directly in jsfiddle.

Comment: You're right, my fault. i've testet it with an space between `<` and `div`. Thats not what the OP have done. I have to take a closer look, next time. Edited my answer.

Comment: And the single/double quote should be interchangeable

Comment: but bad practice.

Comment: You can refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/2373074/5039495