# double or single quotes around attribute values, upper- or lower-case attribute names?

Tags: html

What is regarded as best practice when writing HTML, double or single quotes around attribute values, upper- or lower-case attribute names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the standard naming convention for html/css ids and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028211/what-is-the-standard-naming-convention-for-html-css-ids-and-classes) and [Single vs Double quotes (' vs ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs)

Comment: Lowercase FOR THE LOVE OF GOD. Also, either double or single quotes is fine.

Comment: I'd say this explains it perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154917/13856389

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to use a tool like prettier https://prettier.io
It formats your code every time you save your file.  Then you will never have to think about it again.