# How can I convert a javascript dictionary to a list of html attributes?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to take this:

```js
var sneed = { feed: "and", seed: [ "formerly", "chucks" ] };
```

And produce this:

```html
feed="and" seed="formerly,chucks"
```

But how?
It needs to work in older javascript versions.

My solution:

```js
function arg( d = {} ) { 

        var sl = []; 
        for ( var key in d ) { 
                sl.push( key + '="' + d[key] + '"' );  
        } 
        return sl.join(" "); 
}
```

The problem is, that this will quickly fail if any " is found within any of the strings, which leads me to ask if there is actually a simpler more straightforward way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: Check if any of the values contain `"` and use `'` around the attribute instead of `"`.

Comment: The real solution is to not generate HTML in the first place. Create DOM elements and set the attributes directly.

Comment: @Barmar If the value is a string, that is simple and straightforward. It gets convoluted as different types are introduced.

Comment: You're converting it to a string. You can check after the conversion.

Comment: Note that if `d[key]` is an object, you'll get `seed="[Object object]"`. If you need to handle that, you'll have to check the type before just concatenating.

Comment: @Barmar mmm yeah I see what you are saying. As for "create dom elements", I'm afraid I don't follow.

Comment: or just `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Ry- QBS is a build system based on QML, which itself is based on Qt, which is a framework for c++. Anyways, it uses right now a very old version of javascript, old enough that it doesnt support `let` -- In any case, it is useful for building files which is what I am attempting with this.

Comment: But it supports default arguments to functions?

Comment: @Barmar I am by no means a javascript developer, so don't grill me on this. All I know is that it does not error when I use default arguments. It does however when I use ` or let or other modern conventions.

Comment: @Ry- I don't know if QBS supports the DOM API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether converting the value to a string results in a value containing quotes. If so, use the opposite type of quotes around the attribute value in the HTML string.

if it contains both, use double quotes as the delimiters, and replace any embedded double quotes with `&quot;`.

```js
function arg(d = {}) {
  var sl = [];
  for (var key in d) {
    var value = d[key].toString();
    var delim;
    if (value.includes('"') && value.includes("'")) {
      value = value.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
      delim = '"';
    } else if (value.includes('"')) {
      delim = "'";
    } else {
      delim = '"';
    }
    sl.push(key + '=' + delim + value + delim);
  }
  return sl.join(" ");
}

console.log(arg({ feed: "and", seed: [ "formerly", "chucks" ] }));
console.log(arg({ feed: "and", seed: [ 'The "first"', "chucks" ] }));
console.log(arg({ feed: "and", seed: [ "formerly", "chuc'ks" ] }));
console.log(arg({ feed: "and", seed: [ 'for"erly', "chuc'ks" ] }));
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to use the opposite quote in the `else` block.

Comment: Why do you put, "can't encode" instead of just replacing it with an escaped version?

Comment: Because there are no escapes in HTML attributes.

Comment: Actually, just realized you can use `&#34;`. I'll fix.

Comment: That is interesting: so `&quot;` does not work in attributes, but you could use `&#34;`?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373074/single-vs-double-quotes-vs

Comment: Actually, I just read the W3C spec, it says `&quot` is allowed as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape a string to put it inside an HTML attribute value safely and accurately by replacing the ampersand and quote character with their corresponding HTML entities:

```js
function escapeDoubleQuotedAttributeValue(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
              .replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
}
```

Turning whatever objects you want to support into strings is a separate issue.

```js
function valueToString(value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return value;
    }

    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
        return String(value);
    }

    throw new TypeError('Unsupported value');
}

function htmlAttributes(d) {
    var attributes = [];

    for (var key in d) {
        var stringValue = valueToString(d[key]);
        var escapedValue = escapeDoubleQuotedAttributeValue(stringValue);
        attributes.push(key + '="' + escapedValue + '"');
    }

    return attributes.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: You need to account for the value type.

Comment: @Anon: Sorry, that was the change I meant to be pointing out with the paragraph above. Still won’t serialize arbitrary objects faithfully, though, as there was discussion about in the question comments. What is the generated HTML used for? Are you going to need to deserialize back out of it?

Comment: When I say general, I mean to say that I am not a fan of advanced website frameworks like react, typescript, or even anything with embedded javascript. I am producing a very plain, minimal site. As to the arbitrary objects, it isnt the end of the world if `[object]` or `undefined` ends up making it into the html, although it would be nice if it threw an error.

Comment: @Barmar said, "Because there are no escapes in HTML attributes. – ` when I asked him why he didnt just put in `&quot;` --  Does that mean that your code here needs to be fixed? Barmar seemed to imply that you could however use the numberd escape, `&#34;`

Comment: @Anon Barmar is just not correct in saying "there are no escapes in HTML attributes". `&#34;` will also work.