# Preserving single or double quotes around attributes in browser

Tags: html, quotes, dtd, double-quotes

I want to preserve single or double quotes around html attributes, specifically for innerHTML within the content editable div. I know this is weird requirement, but I am looking for possibilities. So lets say I put html in content editable div from server :

```
<div class="editable">
    PRESS MENU BUTTON<img src='BUTTON_BACK.png' vspace='-16' width='32' height="32">
</div>
```

This should be preserved. But currently in firefox, as I inspect the DOM it just converts all single quotes to double quotes around all attributes.

So the question is :

- Is there any browser configurations to disable this behavior ?
- How can DTD be helpful in this scenario (applicable to only editable section)?
- Any other in-sights ?

Edit: 
   Also when I get the contents of div by innerHTML I get the modified version of its contents , single quotes replaced by double quotes . As [per SGML](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2) there is not such requirement to quote attributes using double quotes.So its not only the developer tools only .

I have already visited SOQs [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/is-it-correct-to-use-single-quotes-for-html-attributes), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273354/are-single-quotes-allowed-in-html),but my question is slightly different.

Comment: ...why? When you inspect the DOM in Firefox, what you're seeing is not a "converted" version of your HTML at all. What you're seeing is the DOM expressed in an HTML-like structure. It has nothing to do with your original HTML, that is long discarded. The syntax of it is not preserved; the syntax is only there to transport the information, after that it becomes irrelevant. So again: why is this an issue?

Comment: @deceze when I echo innerHTML I also see the converted version of the html.

Comment: @deceze the requirment is to not discard that information , its trivial here to keep single or double or whatever I put around attributes. Because there is not such requirement by SGML to put duoble qoutes around attributes check ref:http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: Why is that a "requirement"? Who requires this? What for?

Comment: @deceze I import html fragments mostly images , into db and use browser editable area to edit it . Requirement (client) is to keep the quotes whatever they are. e.g a fragment example: `PRESS MENU BUTTON<img src='BUTTON_BACK.png' vspace='-16' width='32' height="32">`

Answer (score 4):

Those quotation marks aren't actually in the DOM at all; the DOM is a data structure, with string objects for the attribute values.  It doesn't retain any information about whether the strings were single- or double-quoted in the original source, since there's no difference in meaning between the two forms.

The HTML that you see in Firefox's developer tools is not a copy of your HTML source code; it's generated from the DOM data structure.  And since the DOM doesn't include any information about how the strings were quoted in the original source code, the developer tools just quotes them all in a default way when generating new HTML from the DOM.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2 give this reference its also not mandatory to quote attributes using double quotes so the question is why browser converts them ? how to avoid this ?

Comment: It doesn't deliberately "convert" them.  It just doesn't remember how they were originally quoted.  The original HTML text is discarded after it's parsed into a DOM tree.

Comment: thanks for the explaination so there is no way to make browser remember those quotes , even customizing the DTD ?

Comment: A browser *could* be programmed (by the browser's developers) to retain that sort of information, but if the browser doesn't support it then a document can't make the browser do it.  There are other possible variations in the HTML text that the parser will ignore, such as spacing within tags:  `<   foo  />` will produce exactly the same DOM node as `<foo />`.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is a "*carrier* of structured information", it itself is not the information. It's like the envelope around a letter. HTML is used to convey the structural information of the desired DOM from your server to the browser. Once the browser receives this information, it "unpacks" it and constructs the DOM. Then it discards the HTML text, because it has no further use for it; it is now working with the DOM data structure.

There's no place in the DOM for storing what kind of quotes were used to construct a DOM element's attributes. Because it's irrelevant. `foo='bar'` is 100% equivalent to `foo="bar"` to `foo=bar` in terms of expressing an attribute and its value in serialised form. It's always possible to derive a serialised form from the DOM; in other words the DOM can always be written to HTML again from scratch. You can convert HTML → DOM → HTML → DOM → HTML back and forth all day long. However, the specific *formatting* of the HTML will not stick, because it's irrelevant and gets discarded in the conversion.

That's what you're seeing in the DOM inspector or in `.innerHTML`: just a representation of the current DOM expressed in serialised HTML. There's no point in caring about the specific format of that HTML, as long as it expresses the same information. And no, you can't preserve it.

If you really really want that, you'll have to bend over backwards and do a lot of manual HTML processing.

Comment: that make sense, what I thought was that DTD could be customized to override that behavior.

Comment: A DTD is, again, a carrier of information. In this case, it expresses the legal *structure* of a document, i.e. what information may be contained in a document. What you're talking about is at a much more superficial level, the *syntactical* level of a specific representation of this document structure. A DTD is not concerned with syntax, that is regulated by the SGML/XML/HTML specification.