# stop single quote converting to double quote

Tags: php, syntax, echo

I have this line of code (This is pulling a custom field from a WordPress post then uses Jquery Shuffle - http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/):

```
<?php 
     $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_accessories_product', true); 
?>

     <li class="item" data-groups='["<?php echo $data; ?>"]'>
```

which I want to output:

```
<li class="item" data-groups='["prod1"]'>
```

but it outputs this instead:

```
<li class="item" data-groups="["prod1"]">
```

it replaces the single quotes with double quotes which means the script doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems like browser issue, did you tried in another one?

Comment: the output is probably what you want, except you are not checking the actual source code, you are probably checking the DOM with your browser inspector.

Comment: If I go to that website link you provided and check the code, the elements with the 'data-groups` attributes also are in the same format as `data-groups="["photography"]"` so I dont think you have a problem. Is this stopping you from doing something? what problems are you having?

Comment: You might want to reverse the quotes...

Comment: @AlanMachado just checked it in Safari, Chrome and FF. Outputs the same in all.

Comment: @CodeGodie When I go to that link, under the Usage section I see the code:
    data-groups='["photography"]'
where it uses single quotes. If I manually enter the code, ie so it's not dynamically pulling in the variable, the the shuffle works, as it doesn't change the single quote for a double. As soon as I add the php bit within it I get the problem and the shuffle doesn't work.

Comment: _"The HTML that you see in the broswer's developer tools is not a copy of your HTML source code; it's generated from the DOM data structure. And since the DOM doesn't include any information about how the strings were quoted in the original source code, the developer tools just quotes them all in a default way when generating new HTML from the DOM."_ . [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668500/preserving-single-or-double-quotes-around-attributes-in-browser)

Comment: In that case, you need to first show us the actual output of `$data`. Can you run `var_dump($data)` and provide us with that result?

Comment: @Akki I'm afraid that does help

Comment: @CodeGodie an example result is: string(5) "eight", in that instance it should look like: <li class="item" data-groups='["eight"]'>

Comment: ok, when you view the **source code** of your HTML does it look like that as well?

Comment: @CodeGodie No your right when you view source code it does display as it should with single quotes. Clearly that was a red herring as to the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So were you able to find the solution? is this still a problem?

Comment: @CodeGodie Yes, thanks all good now, in the header.php I had a conditional statement if(is_page_template and there was a typo in the template name. Doh! The quote thing through me in the wrong direction. Thanks for the help and pointing out the difference that Dev Tools can make compared to view source.

Comment: No problem. thanks. I will mark this question as closed as you found the answer.