# Attribute options for jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, custom-data-attribute

I have this input with **data-options** attribute.

```
<input class="data" type="text" data-options="{maxDate:'0'}" />
```

I would like to load the **datepicker** using the **data-options** value as options. Now with the following code, doesn't work

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
    var dateOptions=$(this).data('options');
    $(this).datepicker(dateOptions)
});
```

but if I put the option on the js like in the following code, it works:

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({maxDate:'0'})
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/exfLf6o9/

> If is somebody can, I would prefer an answer **without eval**.

Comment: have you tried to do a console.log of dateOptions? What do you get?

Comment: I get what I wrote **{maxDate:'0'}**. You can test it on the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/exfLf6o9/) I've post.

Comment: Updated the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34390622/2293686 and it works fine

Comment: check this: https://jsfiddle.net/exfLf6o9/9/

Comment: @Lidaranis I'm looking for a solution with double marks in the attribute.

Comment: @Vixed You can use double quotes instead of single quotes and escape the double quotes from inside the text. But i think that will be a bit confusing. https://jsfiddle.net/exfLf6o9/10/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jquery data automatically parses JSON strings into objects. You just have to follow the directions from `jQuery.parseJson()`

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Changing your Options From `data-options="{maxDate:'0'}"` to `data-options='{ "maxDate": 0 }'` Works wonders

## **EDIT: 12/28/2015**

Since in XHML you don't want to use single `'` for properties, you can do the oposite and then replace the single quotes with double then parse the json response. `{ 'maxDate': 0 }` then `.replace(/'/g, '"')` and use `$.parseJSON()`

```js
$("input.dataWithoutOptions").each(function() {
   $(this).datepicker({
     maxDate: '0'
   })
 });

 $("input.data").each(function() {
   var dateOptions = $.parseJSON($(this).data('options').replace(/'/g, '"'));
   $(this).datepicker(dateOptions);
 });
```

```css
input {
     display: block;
     margin: 10px 0 20px;
     padding: 5px;
   }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

This has options attr:
<input class="data" type="text" data-options="{ 'maxDate': 0 }" />This is just a date pick:
<input class="dataWithoutOptions" type="text" />
```

## **EDIT: 12/30/2015**

@Lidaranis : Brings up a good point.

You can use escaped characters to avoid regex and parsing json. `{&quot;maxDate&quot;:0}`

```js
$("input.dataWithoutOptions").each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    maxDate: '0'
  })
});

$("input.data").each(function() {
  var dateOptions = $(this).data('options');
  $(this).datepicker(dateOptions);
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

This has options attr:
<input class="data" type="text" data-options="{&quot;maxDate&quot;:0}" />This is just a date pick:
<input class="dataWithoutOptions" type="text" />
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'll never use single marks for an xHtml attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242766/is-it-correct-to-use-single-quotes-for-html-attributes

Comment: @Neoptt, I really like your answer, but can you please fix the single and double mark problem?!

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the simplest answer if you are using jquery. Just do a string replace the quotes and parse the json response, after that it's all downhill from there.

Answer (score 11):

When you call `data` function, it returns string so you have to convert it to an object and then pass it to `datepicker` and remove curly bracket from value of `data-options`.

Solutions:

1- Use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

**Javascript**

```
eval('({' + $(this).data('options') + '})')
```

**HTML**

```
data-options="maxDate:'0'"
```

2- Jquery [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) and surround your data attribute value by `'`

**Javascript**

```
$(this).data('options')
```

**HTML**

```
data-options='{"maxDate":0}'
```

3- use [plugin](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or write custom function([the below code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036429/convert-object-string-to-json#answer-26291352) is written by [@allenhwkim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454252/allenhwkim)).

**Javascript**

```
function JSONize(str) {
  return str
    // wrap keys without quote with valid double quote
    .replace(/([\$\w]+)\s*:/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'":'})    
    // replacing single quote wrapped ones to double quote 
    .replace(/'([^']+)'/g, function(_, $1){return '"'+$1+'"'})         
}

jQuery.parseJSON(JSONize($(this).data('options')));
```

**HTML**

```
data-options="{maxDate:'0'}"
```

**Note: all above solutions are tested and they works.**

```js
$("input.dataWithoutOptions").each(function() {
  $(this).datepicker({
    maxDate: '0'
  })
});

$("input.data").each(function() {
  var dateOptions = eval('({' + $(this).data('options') + '})');

  console.log(typeof($(this).data('options'))); //String

  console.log(typeof(dateOptions)); //Object


  $(this).datepicker(dateOptions)
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


This has options attr:
<input class="data" type="text" data-options="maxDate:'0'" />This is just a date pick:
<input class="dataWithoutOptions" type="text" />
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/3ytqt9gh/1/)

Comment: Your code will show the datepicker but will not apply the options. Take a look https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/3ytqt9gh/

Comment: i have the same idea, tried the same in the jsfiddle and didn't have it to work. +1 for managing the fiddle :)

Comment: @Vixed See the updated answer for better understanding.

Comment: @Vixed Great, Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

the datepicker function needs an object and currently you are passing a string hence you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**Option - 1**

change JavaScript to

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
  var dateOptions=$(this).data('options');
  var options = dateOptions.split(', ');
  var obj = {};
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
      var item = opt.split(':');
      obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  });

  $(this).datepicker(obj);
});
```

and change html to

```
<input class="data" type="text" data-options="maxDate:'0'"/>
```

And no eval()

see the javascript fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exfLf6o9/7/

**Option - 2**

JavaScript

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
  var dateOptions=$(this).data('options');
  dateOptions = dateOptions.substring(1,dateOptions.length-1);
  var options = dateOptions.split(', ');
  var obj = {};
  options.forEach(function(opt) {
      var item = opt.split(':');
      obj[item[0]] = item[1];
  });

  $(this).datepicker(obj);
});
```

and leave html as it is

see the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exfLf6o9/8/

**Option - 3**

change html to

```
<input class="data" type="text" data-options='{"maxDate":"0"}' />
```

and in javascript

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
  var dateOptions=$(this).data('options');
  $(this).datepicker(dateOptions);
});
```

using `eval()` is not recommended in JavaScript

Please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/exfLf6o9/5/

Comment: Can you fiddle your answer?

Comment: fiddle added for this answer!

Comment: Doesn't works... check your fiddle. the maxDate 0 is today, but your fiddle shows all the future till the end of time :{

Comment: Sorry, but I'll never use single marks for an xHtml attribute.

Comment: added another option. Fiddles are updated and tested. Working fine

Answer (score 0):

`data()` returns a string when `datepicker()` is expecting an object. The solution is to convert the string to an object:

```
$("input.data").each(function(){
    var dateOptions = $(this).data('options');
    var dateOptionsAsObject = JSON.parse(dateOptions.replace(/([\w|\-|\_]+:)/g,"\"$1\":"));
    $(this).datepicker(dateOptionsAsObject);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to throw out the lazy-loading technique, since no one mentioned it.

```
<div class="data" data-max-date="0"></div>
```

`$.data()` will automatically camelCase your data attributes and attempt to type cast. i.e. the above html attribute data will become: `{ maxDate: 0 }`

```
$('.data').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.datepicker($this.data());
});
```